# Add existing Object into Database with ORM (RedBean Php)

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

Hello To All Stackoverflow Users , I have a class that create object for me called Images, In orm concepts (like Hibernate or something like that) we can add existing object directly(I know it have sub process in it) to database like orm.save(object) but in RedBeanPhp I can't find a method or way to store/save my object directly so , I need use R::dispense('tableNameINeed') and from object the method return add my value / key into it! someone know how I can adding the object directly?

the code I have :

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/rb-mysql.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../Models/Image/Image.php';

R::setup("mysql:host=$databasePath;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

function insertImageTemplate(Image $image){
  
    $isConnected = R::testConnection();
    if($isConnected){
    $imageToDatabase = R::dispense('images');

    $imageToDatabase->category = $image->getCategory();
    $imageToDatabase->height = $image->getHeight();
    $imageToDatabase->imageBoundary = $image->getImageBoundary();
    $imageToDatabase->imgaes = $image->getImgaes();
    $imageToDatabase->type = $image->getType();
    $imageToDatabase->user = $image->getUser();
    $imageToDatabase->width = $image->getWidth();
    R::store($imageToDatabase);
    }
}
```

The code I need Something Looks like

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/rb-mysql.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../Models/Image/Image.php';

R::setup("mysql:host=$databasePath;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

function insertImageTemplate(Image $image){
  
    $isConnected = R::testConnection();
    if($isConnected){

    R::store($image);
    }
}
```